# First hitting time inequality

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $X_t$ be a continuous time stochastic process. Define the first hitting time of $X$ as $\tau = \inf~\{ t \leq t': \lvert X_t \rvert \geq \lambda \}$ for some $\lambda$, $t'$

It is a known fact that $\{ \max_{t \leq t'} \lvert X_t \rvert \geq \ \lambda \} = \{ \tau \leq t' \}$. My Professor claimed in addition that $\{ \tau \leq t' \} \subseteq \{ \lvert X_{\tau \land t' } \rvert \geq \ \lambda \} \} $. However, I don't see why the $\subseteq$ is not just an $=$ . My reasoning is like this: at $|X_{\tau}|$ the value of the process is exactly $\lambda$. However, $|X_{\tau \land t'}|$ is just $|X_{\tau}|$ when $\tau < t'$, and in the case when $ \tau = t'$ we have that $|X_{\tau}| = |X_{t'}| = \lambda$. Where am I going wrong with this proof?

Comment: @drhab yes, exactly

Comment: Your definition of $\tau$ suggests that $\tau=+\infty$ (infinum of empty set) if $|X_t|<\lambda$ for every $t\leq t'$. Is that really the intention?

Comment: @drhab I believe so: isn't the point of the first stopping time to be defined like this ? If we instead defined it as $\sigma = \tau \land t'$, if we just observe $\sigma$ and we see $\sigma=t'$ we don't know if it is because "time ran out" or because the process hit $\lambda$? Or am I not understanding where you are getting at?

Comment: Never mind my comments then. I am not too familiar with stopping times but rather expected something like  $\tau = \inf~\{ t: \lvert X_t \rvert \geq \lambda \}$ where $X_t$ is defined for every $t\in[0,\infty)$ and the probability that some $t$ exists with $|X_t|\geq\lambda$ is $1$. This interpretation can be completely wrong though, so don't take it too serious.